# Customizing HttpWebRequest Header Upper/Lower Case Names?

Tags: c#, vb.net, http-headers, httpwebrequest

Is it possible to overide the way that the Accept/Content-Type/User-Agent headers are set?

I am asking because I have a program that uses HttpWebRequest to login to an account on a website, check the stats of my account & report all data in a program. The website that this is used on also gets a lot of spam & they have now started blocking any requests that do not explicitly send "accept:" in a header, whereas HttpWebRequest sends "Accept:" (Upper Case A).

Using CharlesProxy to check, repeat & change the code I can confirm that the issue is down to the capital/lower case A in the 'Accept' header only.

Using request.Accept='' always sets the header to "Accept".
Setting custom headers is not allowed either: request.headers.add("accept","xx")

Comment: That's a weird spam protection as the HTTP standard (rfc [2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.1) / [7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.3.2)) does not explicitly define whether it has to be capitalized but always uses uppercase examples. I've checked in chrome the raw http request output and it too sends `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml` (**all** headers are capitalized) so technically you should not be able to access the page using chrome?

Comment: Are you able to ask them to use some other anti-"spam" measure, such as a user-defined header? (Apparently X-headers have been deprecated: [RFC 6648](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6648).)

Comment: @Longoon12000 - In Chrome I also see the header as lower case 'accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' - When using CharlesProxy. Which also shows upper case 'Accept' when monitoring traffic from HttpWebRequest. Unless is is a forced header via an AJAX call, but I would imagine this would stick to the browser's default headers still.